# Declaring a template-class object: Error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++

When I try to build my project, I get the error message "`error: no matching function for call to 'Ringbuffer<void*>::Ringbuffer()'`". This is the code that doesn't work, and I wonder why C++ even tries to call "`Ringbuffer()`" since I only want to declare an object in `Producer`. The constructor of `Ringbuffer` takes three arguments. Has anyone an idea? Thanks a lot!

```
#include "Ringbuffer.h"
    
class Producer{
    private:

    Ringbuffer<void*> rbuf;
public:
    Producer();
};

Producer::Producer(){

}
```

Comment: how do you expect the `rbuf` member to be constructed, if not by calling its constructor?

Answer (score 1):

> why C++ even tries to call "Ringbuffer()"

Because `rbuf` is a member of `Producer` and when you construct a `Producer` that member is constructed as well. If you don't do it explicitly, then `rbuf` is implicilty default constructed.

> The constructor of Ringbuffer takes three arguments.

When `Ringbuffer` has no default constructor (one that can be called without parameter) but only one with 3 arguments, then it cannot be default constructed.

> Has anyone an idea?

Call the constructor:

```
Producer::Producer() : rdbuf(foo,bar,baz)  {

}
```

where `foo`,`bar` and `baz` are the parameters you want to use to construct the `Ringbuffer`.